# How to Sort Listview Columns Containing Strings & Integers?

Tags: c#, vb.net, listview, sorting

### General Information

I have a ListView containing multiple columns. I have used a [Microsoft Method to sort my ListView Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229643%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). The ListView  is populated by a SQL Query which correctly sorts Strings and Integers together (*code shown below*). For Example:

**String & Integer Sorting Problem**

The following `JobNumber` **strings** are considered as sorted

*"10", "1", "2", "3"*

Using my SQL Query, they will become

*"1", "2", "3", "10"*

---

### SQL String & Integer Sorter

Here is the Query I use to sort Strings and Integers correctly

```
SELECT PK_BillHeader, JobNumber, Description
FROM dbo.BillHeaders 
ORDER BY Case IsNumeric(JobNumber) 
    When 1 Then Replicate('0', 50 - Len(JobNumber)) + JobNumber 
        Else JobNumber 
    End
```

This enters zeros until it gets the maximum length of my SQL column (50 chars) minus the `JobNumber`'s current length. That way, everything is considered as a string (including integers) which can then be sorted out correctly.

---

### My Problem

When I click on the ListView Column Header (causing it to sort), it stops sorting the strings and integers correctly as it did with my SQL query. Instead, it sorts everything as a string which replicates my "*String & Integer*" sort problem once more ... What is more, if I have decimal values (*second picture*), it sorts them out pretty weird (*see my compare code*)

[image: Machine Number String & Integer Problem] [image: Money Sort]

**Compare Code**

```
Public Function [Compare](ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer.Compare
        Dim xItem As clsSortWrapper = CType(x, clsSortWrapper)
        Dim yItem As clsSortWrapper = CType(y, clsSortWrapper)

        Dim xText As String = xItem.sortItem.SubItems(xItem.sortColumn).Text
        Dim yText As String = yItem.sortItem.SubItems(yItem.sortColumn).Text

        If Decimal.TryParse(xText, vbNull) Then xText = xText.PadLeft(10, "0"c)
        If Decimal.TryParse(yText, vbNull) Then yText = yText.PadLeft(10, "0"c)
        Return xText.CompareTo(yText) * IIf(Me.ascending, 1, -1)
    End Function
```

Is there a simpler way to acheive my result of sorting a ListView with Strings and Integers?

---

*Note:*

I omitted posting the [ListView Sort code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229643%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) here because it would've clustered the post quite a bit. I provided the link which explains it thoroughly.

Comment: Also an out off topic hint:
If you're familiar with C# I would suggest you to add the tag C#, because it has ten times more followers than VB.NET.

Comment: @FabianBigler Thanks! I'll do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way.  In your Sort code pad the strings with 0's when you call CompareTo.

```
If Integer.TryParse(xText, VBNull) Then
      xText = xText.PadLeft(6, "0"c)
End If
If Integer.TryParse(yText, VBNull) Then
      yText = yText.PadLeft(6, "0"c)
End If
Return xText.CompareTo(yText) * IIf(Me.ascending, 1, -1)
```

This way "11004" will be compared as "011004" and appear before "110030", but the padding is only for comparison, the value will still be displayed as "11004".

UPDATE:

Normal strings will be sorted without padding now.

Comment: Cool! +1 that worked pretty good. It sorted most of it correctly. After scrolling for a while I saw this: http://i.imgur.com/b9bfSeT.png ... The strings should appear after the numbers. Why is it that some are in between the numbers?

Comment: @Alex This is pretty nice if you have only strings in number format such as "11104", but will fail if you also have "normal" strings like "Elec" or "TEMP".

Comment: Those values must be returned by you SQL query.  They appear there be cause they are shorter than 6 characters.  A simple Integer.TryParse to check if the values are integers before you do the comparison, then the padding if they are Integers and no padding if they're not

Comment: @tinstaafl What if I have decimal values like so: i.imgur.com/DwgDHgy.png ...? I tried Decimal.TryParse(..) but that didn't work either.

Comment: Nvm. Figured it out ... What I did was split the string if it finds a decimal place. If it does, then I pad the number and afterwards apply it's decimals. This makes it sort perfectly.

Comment: Double.TryParse should have worked.  But the padding might have to be adjusted.  add one for the decimal and one for each decimal place.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1: Codesnippet from Natural Comparer** Whole source code is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22978/Implementing-the-NET-IComparer-interface-to-get-a)

This will sort the way you described in your question, also supporting roman values ('D', 'X', etc.).

```
int System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<string>.Compare(string string1, 
                                                 string string2)
{
  mParser1.Init(string1);
  mParser2.Init(string2);
  int result;
  do
  {
    if (mParser1.TokenType == TokenType.Numerical & 
                 mParser2.TokenType == TokenType.Numerical)
      // both string1 and string2 are numerical 
      result = decimal.Compare(mParser1.NumericalValue, mParser2.NumericalValue);
    else
      result = string.Compare(mParser1.StringValue, mParser2.StringValue);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    else
    {
      mParser1.NextToken();
      mParser2.NextToken();
    }
  } while (!(mParser1.TokenType == TokenType.Nothing & 
             mParser2.TokenType == TokenType.Nothing));  
  return 0; //identical 
}
```

---

**Approach #2: Easy, customized Comparer (Without Roman values)**

```
class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        int xVal, yVal;
        var xIsNumeric = int.TryParse( x, out xVal );
        var yIsNumeric= int.TryParse( y, out yVal );

        if (xIsNumeric && yIsNumeric)
            return xVal.CompareTo(yVal);
        if (!xIsNumeric && !yIsNumeric)
            return x.CompareTo(y);
        if (xIsNumeric )           
            return -1;
        return 1;   
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the help, thanks. I'll check and see what I can do with this

Comment: @Alex the whole point is to use a custom IComparer.
Both comparers work similar. You can doublecheck it and give me feedback, which approach works for you.

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing the NaturalComparer ... Where does "mParser" come from? I can't seem to find the equivalent in VB.Net

Comment: @Alex: That's why I called it a Codesnippet! The whole code source is on codeproject (link is in answer):
I would recommend you the second approach anyway, if you don't need to handle roman values.

Comment: Yes I know, I've been on CodeProject for a while and I've been trying to apply their fix. I might have found a solution on my own though (hopefully)... If not I'll check out the second approach.

Comment: @Alex Sure just choose the solution which suits you best.