# How to sort listbox with letters and numbers ascendent by numbers vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a listbox with something like this:

```
test|10
name|44
blabla|16
```

and I want sort those items by the number they have at the end (10 44 16), such that they become ordered like this:

```
name|44
blabla|16
test|10
```

Comment: Can you show us some code you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are actually looking for descending order.  Anyways, here is a solution from one list to another:

```
Dim myList As List(Of String) = {"test|10", "name|44", "blabla|16"}.ToList
Dim orderedList As List(Of String) = (From item In myList Order By item.Substring(item.IndexOf("|") + 1) Descending Select item).ToList
```

EDIT:  This will sort the items as strings, which means that if you have 44, 16, 100, and 10, it would look like this after being sorted: 44, 16, 100, 10.  This is probably not what you want, so you should parse the numbers out into integers so that they sort numerically.  Try this:

```
Dim myList As List(Of String) = {"test|10", "name|44", "blabla|16", "foo|100"}.ToList
Dim orderedList As List(Of String) = (From item In myList Order By Integer.Parse(item.Substring(item.IndexOf("|") + 1)) Descending Select item).ToList
```

Comment: i think is good but i dont have only those items : test name blabla i have a large list

Comment: So use your large list instead.  If it is a listbox then you should refer to the .Items property rather than the listbox itself.

Comment: Dim orderedList As List(Of String) = (From item In ListBox1.Items Order By item.Substring(item.IndexOf("|") + 1) Descending).ToList

and it don't work

Comment: That's because ListBox1.Items isn't a collection of String.  It's a ListItemCollection.

Comment: so how i can convert it :D ?

Comment: To convert it you can use 'ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String)()'.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is the `IComparer Interface`

Please take a look at 
[Natural Comparer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22978/Implementing-the-NET-IComparer-interface-to-get-a) or [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351484/how-to-sort-listview-columns-containing-strings-integers/17351619#17351619).

Comment: I just changed the answer a bit. Please doublecheck it.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to sort the items before they get into the listbox, like this:

I am going to create an example class to hold the items in the listbox, like this:

```
Public Class Item
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set
            m_Name = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Name As String
    Public Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Value
        End Get
        Set
            m_Value = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Value As Integer
End Class
```

Note: You can create whatever class name you want and whatever property names you want, I choose `Item`, `Name` and `Value`, but they can be any valid name.

Now you create a `List(Of T)` to hold these items, like this:

```
Dim listOfItems = New List(Of Item)
```

Then you will need to sort the list and store, like this:

```
Dim sortedListOfItems = listOfItems.OrderBy(Function(i) i.Value).ToList()
```

Note: This is using `LINQ` to sort the list via the `OrderBy` extension method.

Finally, you want to bind this sorted list to your listbox control.

Comment: There is no longer a need to explicitly declare get/set methods if you are using the default get/set.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin - Agreed, but I was not sure if the poster knew what automatic properties were so I erred on the side of caution.

Comment: There is a trailing "()" while declaring the list?

Comment: @abhitalks - sorry that is not necessary, in C# it is and I had a brain fart when converting it to VB.NET, answer updated.

Comment: @GeorgeOprea - what part(s) do you not understand?

Comment: the code from Douglas Barbin it's good but i need somehow to replace mylist with items from my listbox1 ....