# Sorting a listbox by integers

Tags: vb.net, class, sorting, listbox

I am trying to sort a listbox which has both text and string in it, I was having a look at this post and was trying to use the method suggested by the user Karl Anderson, [How to sort listbox with letters and numbers ascendent by numbers vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057755/how-to-sort-listbox-with-letters-and-numbers-ascendent-by-numbers-vb-net/28925784#28925784).

At the end of the post he says you need to "bind the sorted list to the list control", this is where I am stuck because I am not sure how to do this or use this method to sort the listbox on a checkbox/button click, could anyone help me please? Thankyou
The information in the listboxes is read from text files, the information is formatted like this:

- Name: Example Address:43
- Name: Another Example Address: 14

  ```
  If RadioButton_1.Checked = True Then
      Do Until textreader1.Peek = -1
          Readline = textreader1.ReadLine()

          Line_text(i) = Readline

          ListBox_Readto.Items.Add(Line_text(i))

          i = i + 1
      Loop
  ```

Comment: Really you should add the code that fill your listbox

Comment: @Steve sorry could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: Do you have written the code that fill the ListBox? I think that you should add to your question that code. It is there that you need to order your data in such a way that, after adding the items, the ListBox presents its content in an ordered way

Comment: @Steve I've updated it now hopefully its a bit clearer now

Answer (score 0):

Don't add directly to the listbox but instead build a collection, sort, and then databind to the listbox.

Something like this:

```
Dim items as new List(of String)
If RadioButton_1.Checked = True Then
 Do Until textreader1.Peek = -1
    Readline = textreader1.ReadLine()
    Line_text(i) = Readline
    items.add(Readline)  
    i = i + 1 
Loop

items.sorthowever()
ListBox_Readto.dataSource = items
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and Sorry for the late reply, would you be able to give me an example of how you would then sort the collection by the highest address at the end please, the method I tried to use wouldn't work because it can't deal with the string to integer of my code.